# jquery.validate not working for select box

Tags: php, jquery, css, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to give a validation rules for my form.. Foe every field it is working fine but for select box it is not coming fine,,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('form#EnrollmentAccountHolderInformationForm').validate({
//           ignore: function(){
//              return $('form#EnrollmentAccountHolderInformationForm input:hidden, form#EnrollmentAccountHolderInformationForm select');
//           },
             debug: false,
            rules: {
                "data[Enrollment][personalinfo_source]": {
                required:true
                },
                "data[Enrollment][person_last_name]": {
                required:true
                }
          }
    });
```

this is my select box name ;- data[Enrollment][personalinfo_source]

Here is code for select box:--

```
<h4 style="line-height:17px;">How did you hear <br/>about us?*</h4> 
                            <?php $options = array(
                                'Event Sponsorship' => 'Event Sponsorship',
                                'Internet'=>'Internet',
                                'Newspaper' => 'Newspaper',
                                'Outdoor Advertising' =>'Outdoor Advertising',
                                'Radio' => 'Radio',
                                'Telemarketing' => 'Telemarketing',
                                'Television' => 'Television',
                                'Social Media' =>'Social Media',
                                'Other'=>'Other');
                                 echo $this->Form->input('personalinfo_source',array('label'=>false,'id'=>'select','class' => "selectbox",'div'=>false,'options'=>$options, 'tabindex' => '16', 'empty' => 'Select','style' => "width:215px;"));
                            ?>
                            <div style="clear:both"> </div>
```

Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your HTML code? as per your php code ('id'=>'select'). select box id is "select" not "EnrollmentAccountHolderInformationForm", i am not sure...